# Resetting a formik form in react-native on navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, formik, react-navigation-v5

I am trying to create a React Native app that can create and edit entities.

For example, users.

I have a formik form that takes first and last name, as well as an email address.
If a user params is passed, then the form should take on those values.

However, it only works the first time.  After that, the form keeps the first values.

How can I force the form to be reevaluated?

```
function FormScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  const formikRef = React.createRef();
  const initialValues = { firstName: "", lastName: "", email: "" };

  if (route.params && route.params.user) {
    if (route.params.user.firstName) {
      initialValues.firstName = route.params.user.firstName;
    }
    if (route.params.user.lastName) {
      initialValues.lastName = route.params.user.lastName;
    }
    if (route.params.user.email) {
      initialValues.email = route.params.user.email;
    }
  }

  const unsubscribeBlur = navigation.addListener("blur", (e) => {
    console.log("form blur");
    if (formikRef.current) {
      console.log("form reset");
      formikRef.current?.resetForm();
    }
  });

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Formik
        innerRef={formikRef}
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={Yup.object({
          firstName: Yup.string()
            .max(15, "Must be 15 characters or less")
            .required("Required"),
          lastName: Yup.string()
            .max(20, "Must be 20 characters or less")
            .required("Required"),
          email: Yup.string()
            .email("Invalid email address")
            .required("Required"),
        })}
        onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            setSubmitting(false);
          }, 400);
        }}
      >
        <Form>
          <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
          <Field name="firstName" type="text" />
          <ErrorMessage name="firstName" />

          <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <Field name="lastName" type="text" />
          <ErrorMessage name="lastName" />

          <label htmlFor="email">Email Address</label>
          <Field name="email" type="email" />
          <ErrorMessage name="email" />

          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    </View>
  );
}

export default FormScreen;
```

I have code in there to reset the form on blur but the reset doesn't seem to do anything.

You can find the complete code in a snack.
https://snack.expo.io/@hackzilla/create-and-edit-with-formik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using a tab navigator. The home and form screen will not reMount when you toggle between them.So the formik will not load the new initialValues.In your way,you can reset the form using route params everytime the form screen is focused.But a better way is using a stack navigator,every time create a form using a new instance.

```
   useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      if (formikRef.current) {
        console.log("form reset");
        formikRef.current?.setValues(initialValues);
      }
    })
  );
```

Comment: It's worth noting that I needed a second parameter to useFocusEffect and I needed to also call resetForm to reset the error messages.

    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
            if (formikRef.current) {
                console.log("form reset");
                formikRef.current?.resetForm();
                formikRef.current?.setValues(initialValues);
            }
        }, [route.params])
    );

Also the required import is: import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/native";

Comment: The crucial problem is that Formik will not reload the initialValues after the first load. If you have known this there are a lot of ways to solve it.

Comment: I had eventually figured that out..  but the lack of documentation was frustrating.
It also feels like I was the only one to put formik in a navigation.

Answer (score 0):

We can reset the form after submit, so that it will clear all the fields. Please try by replacing your submit method with below mentioned code.

```
 onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            setSubmitting(false);
            // reset the fields after submit
            resetForm();
          }, 400);
        }}
```

Comment: This is ok, but my issue was predominately the form not being cleared in all scenarios.  For example, this wouldn't work if some one started filling out the form and then decided to edit a different one.